# Add time & increment 1 sec for every file name in control M

Tags: control-m

I am trying to append current time to the file. But, there is one thing that I need is the FTP job that I am using is transferring multiple files and all the files have same name expect for the time that we are appending to it. Could any one tell me how I can add one second/ minute to the %%TIME param so that I can pass it to my file name

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you're using the AFT/MFT module. If so, you can use [T] to get the timestamp and then [C#] to get a counter number.

[N]__[T]_[C3].[E]    -> this will give you something like MyFileName__235703_001.txt

If, however, you want to stick with using %%TIME you can create your own local variable based on %%TIME and then use the "%%PLUS 1" numeric expression to create a modified variable.